# Form usability: Input type selector

Tags: forms, input-fields, selection

I'm working on the form right now. There's part where user have to input data which can be two different type. For example input field where user can type money amount and then select currency. I'm not sure how this should be called. How would you handle this situation when theres two different units?

Here's couple ways what I've been thinking.

Option1:

[image]

Option2:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combined data and unit form field](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/66847/combined-data-and-unit-form-field)

Comment: Not quite but that was good! Thanks for that it gave me confirmation that I'm on the right way. In my case I have only two options for unit. Should I make it with dropdown or radio button?(see quesion images)

Comment: I'll add that you can improve your selector by having the more popular one selected by default. That way most of your users don't have to change to the other option.

Comment: @Robert, if you only have two options and both are short, like what you've shown, then I think radios are better since I can see all my options at once. With the dropdown, I have to open it to see my options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on how many options you have for Unit type?
If you have 2 options for Unit, the best solution here is Option 2. You save 1 click/tap for the user.

If the list for Unit is >2 I would use the Option 1 as it can get super messy when you have multiple radios.

Did you consider having a segmented controller there?

[image]

Comment: Nice! Thanks for the answer. I have only two options in my case so radio buttons might be good for me.

About that segmented version. In my case I have two different kind of units course/academic credits, "opintopiste" and "osaamispiste". Those words can't have abbreviation and they dont have symbols like currencies. Are those words too long for segmented version?

Comment: I Googled more info about segmented controller and it seems to be ok put longer words to segment. I still think I'll go with the radio buttons. Thanks!